# Does an NServiceBus endpoint with SQL Server transport and Windows authentication need to be installed as the user running the service?

Tags: nservicebus

I'm installing an NServiceBus 4.x endpoint which uses SQL Server transport.  While running the installer (via Octopus Deploy, which runs as Local System by default)...

`.\NServiceBus.Host.exe /install NServiceBus.Production /serviceName=$name /username:"$username" /password:"$password`

... I get an error:

`Failed to execute installers: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\MACHINENAME$'.`

This is the expected behavior if the installer connects to SQL Server when it's run: Local System becomes the computer account when it leaves the box and the computer account does not have access to the transport database.

However, I do not intend to run the endpoint as Local System.  Instead, I intend to use a domain service account which does have access to the transport database, so...

Is it possible to install an NServiceBus endpoint using SQL Server transport as a user who does not have access to the transport database?

Bonus question: Has this behavior been changed in versions of NServiceBus later than 4.x?

Comment: We are looking at this my colleague Ramon will get back to you tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `NServiceBus.Host.exe` is executed with the credentials of as you say Octopus Deploy and `/install` runs the NServiceBus installers.

Some alternatives:

1. Run Octopus Deploy Agent with permissions that also allows doing schema changes on the database during this deployment phase.
2. Instead of executing the host directly, launch a shell with different credentials so that the host is run with credentials that have appropriate permissions.
3. Do not use the host, but use self-hosting. Register that service via `sc.exe` to register the windows service with the right credentials, and use `endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers()` to control if installers must be run.

   - https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/operations/installers
   - https://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/windows-service/
   - https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/windows-service#installation
4. Use self-hosting as in (3), don't use `endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers()` but script all tasks and let these run independently of the 'windows service' registration task. Alternatively, you can instead use  `sc.exe` to register the `NServiceBus.Host.exe` so that the `/install` will not be run.

   - That means generating most scripts yourself. Some components have script generators but our docs have a lot of guidance on scripting

     - https://docs.particular.net/search?q=script

I would advise NOT to just always run `endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers()` on an endpoint. You should distinguish between a deployment and runtime. During deployment you would create tables, schemas etc. but at runtime, that account should not have the permissions to create or drop tables and run least privilege.